# Backbone - Nested Model with Model Binder

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

ModelBinder doesn't seem to work together with nested model( backbone-nested project) ..the changes from model don't get propogated to the nested elements.On changing the input value the span value doesn't change...If NestedModel is replace with DeepModel it works. Again the NestedModel also works if the person.name is removed and Model has just one level(lastName and firstName).

```
    <script type='text/coffeescript'>
        $ ->
            class MyModel extends Backbone.NestedModel
                defaults:
                    person:
                        name :
                            firstName: 'Bob'
                            lastName: 'Sass' 

            window.model = new MyModel

            FormView = Backbone.View.extend
                initialize: ->
                    @modelBinder = new Backbone.ModelBinder();
                    @modelBinder.bind(@model,@el)
                el: '#frm'

            view = new FormView model: model

    </script>


<body>
    <form method="post" action="/test" id='frm'>
        <div id="welcome"> Welcome, <span id='person.name.firstName'></span> <span id='person.name.lastName'></span>
        <br><br>
        Edit your information:
            <input type="text" name="person.name.firstName" value="zz"/>
            <input type="text" name="person.name.lastName" value="nn"/></div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same problem. I found success using Backbone.ModelBinder in conjunction with [backbone-associations](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations). It allowed me to use ModelBinder with my nested models and accomplish what you are describing.

I took the example you posted and created a fiddle [Using Backbone.ModelBinder with backbone-associations](http://jsfiddle.net/scottluskcis/779TS/1/) using your example. Check it out and see if it answers your question.

The JavaScript ends up looking like this:

```js
    var Name = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        defaults: { 'firstName': '', 'lastName': '' }
    }); 

    var Person = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        defaults: { 'name': null }, 

        // create a relation for our nested model  
        relations: [{
            'type': Backbone.One,
            'key': 'name',
            'relatedModel': Name
        }]
    });

    var MyModel = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        defaults: { 'person': null }, 

        // create a relation for our nested model
        relations: [{
            'type': Backbone.One,
            'key': 'person',
            'relatedModel': Person
        }]
    });

    var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({   
        el: '#frm', 

        initialize: function() {
            this._modelBinder = new Backbone.ModelBinder(); 
        }, 

        render: function() {

            var bindingsHash = {
                'person.name.firstName': [
                    { 'selector': '#firstName' },
                    { 'selector': '[name=firstName]' }
                ],
                'person.name.lastName': [
                    { 'selector': '#lastName' },
                    { 'selector': '[name=lastName]' }
                ]
            }; 

            this._modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el, bindingsHash);   
        }, 

        close: function() {
            this._modelBinder.unbind();    
        }
    });

    // create the model     
    var modelInfo = new MyModel({
        'person': {
            'name': {
                'firstName': 'Bob',
                'lastName': 'Sass'
            }
        }
    }); 

    // create the view and render 
    var view = new FormView({ model: modelInfo }); 
    view.render();
```